# Python3 mock on setup

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock some 3rd part library on setup so i can pretend it works as expected on my code.

I was able to mock it locally on which i configure all the returns on the function itself

```
    class MockConnecton:
        def __init__(self):
            self._ch = Mock()

        def channel(self):
            return self._ch

    class QEmiterTest(unittest.TestCase):
        @patch('task_queues.queue.pika.BlockingConnection')
        @patch('task_queues.queue.pika.ConnectionParameters')
        def test_emiter(self,mock_params,mock_block):
            config = {
                'host':'mq',
                'exchange':'test'
            }
            params =  {"FOO":"BAR"}
            mock_params.return_value = params
            conn = MockConnecton()
            mock_conn = Mock(wraps=conn)
            mock_block.return_value = mock_conn
            emitter = QEmitter(config['host'],config['exchange'])
            mock_params.assert_called_with(config['host'])
            mock_block.assert_called_with(params)
            mock_conn.channel.assert_called_with()
            conn._ch.exchange_declare.assert_called_with(exchange=config['exchange'],type='topic')
```

But when i try to move from this approach to a cleaner one with the [mock start/stop](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop) i receive an error on the assertion:

> AttributeError: '_patch' object has no attribute 'assert_called_with'

I am trying to port it like this

```
    class QEmiterTest(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            mock_params = patch('task_queues.queue.pika.ConnectionParameters')
            mock_block = patch('task_queues.queue.pika.BlockingConnection')
            self.params_ret =  {"FOO":"BAR"}
            mock_params.return_value = self.params_ret
            conn = MockConnecton()
            self.mock_conn = Mock(wraps=conn)
            mock_block.return_value = self.mock_conn
            self.patch_params = mock_params
            self.patch_block = mock_block
            self.patch_params.start()
            self.patch_block.start()

        def test_emiter(self):
            config = {
                'host':'mq',
                'exchange':'test'
            }
            emitter = QEmitter(config['host'],config['exchange'])
            self.patch_params.assert_called_with(config['host'])
            self.patch_block.assert_called_with(self.params_ret)
            self.mock_conn.channel.assert_called_with()
            self.mock_conn._ch.exchange_declare.assert_called_with(exchange=config['exchange'],type='topic')

        def tearDown(self):
            self.patch_params.stop()
            self.patch_block.stop()
```

I may not fully understand the start and stop, i was under the assumpton that on setup it would apply the patch and by it's reference i would be able to make assertions . I also welcome any suggestons on how to make several mocks cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) object are patch and not mock. `mock` framework have two main duties:

1. Mock object used to record the call and follow your screenplay
2. Patch methods and object used to replace reference by something that you can use to sensor or simulate some behaviors

A lot of time we can use patch to install mocks... but patch are not mock.

[`patch.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop) return the new reference (often a mock) used to patch the original one.

```
def setUp(self):
            self.params_ret =  {"FOO":"BAR"}
            self.mock_conn = Mock(wraps=conn)
            self.patch_params = patch('task_queues.queue.pika.ConnectionParameters', return_value = self.params_ret)
            self.patch_block = patch('task_queues.queue.pika.BlockingConnection', return_value=self.mock_conn)
            mock_params = self.patch_params.start()
            mock_block = self.patch_block.start()
```